# Visual Studio 2017 change language of current file?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

I have a `*.cs.bak` file that I want to temporarily (= no permanent settings) treat as C# in Visual Studio 2017.

I only found out that Visual Studio Code can do it, but looking to do the same in visual studio yielded no results, so I ask the internet about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it in your project with the add existing item. Inside VS just click on your csproj and select Add -> Existing item and select your .bak.

After that, If you click on the file in Solution Explorer and look at the Properties window, you'll see a property called "Build Action". This defines whether the file will be treated like code ("Compile"), included as a resource ("Embedded Resource"), ignored ("None")...

Comment: Will that change the syntax highlighting too? What about an opened file that is not part of a project?

Comment: Another option is just paste the .bak file inside your folder project. There is a button in the Solution Explorer called “Show All Files” (If the button isn't there, make sure you have the project selected and not the solution.) Click that button and Visual Studio will that will show all the files in the project folder and not just those that are included in the project.

Comment: But what if I have only double clicked the file to edit with VS and there is no project loaded? I wanted to do something like VS Code or IntelliJ...